# How to transfom decoder_target_data to the right shape for Model ouputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.6

I'm trying to code a word-level machine translation using keras, with an architecture encoder-decoder, using word_embedding and force teaching technique. I read that target_answer has to be the same that decoder_inputs but one word shift. The problem is that when I create my model and this's the last part of `model.summary()`

```
lstm (LSTM)       [(None, 128), (None, 91648     embedding[0][0]                  
___________________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)     [(None, 100, 128), ( 91648   embedding_2[0][0]                
                                                                 lstm[0][1]                       
                                                                 lstm[0][2]                       
___________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)   (None, 100, 10001)   1290129     lstm_2[0][0]
```

decoder_outputs has 3 dimensional, so target_answer should be transformed into a 3 dimensional array. How can i do that??
target_answer is an array with the index_word of the vocabulary [4 52 69 5 6 ....]

I'm following this keras example https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq.py but this one is character-level.

I tried to use this

```
target_answer = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(answers, mode='binary')
```

but it just gives me a 2dimensional array and it hasn't the same shape of decoder_ouputs

This is my model

```
latent_dim = 128
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_amount_tokens,))
word_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=vocabulary_size+2, output_dim=embedding_dim,\
                           input_length=max_amount_tokens, weights = [embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(encoder_inputs)


x, state_h, state_c = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)(word_embedding)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_amount_tokens,))
word_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=vocabulary_size+2, output_dim=embedding_dim, \
                           input_length=max_amount_tokens, weights = [embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(decoder_inputs)


decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim,  return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(word_embedding, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(vocabulary_size + 1, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)


model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit([input_questions_encoded, input_answers_encoded], target_answer, epochs=150, batch_size=64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Encoder Decoder with Teacher Forcing

Lets take an example and see what it mean by Teacher Forcing.

Input: `[1,2,3]` and the target Decoded Output: `[ 1, 3, 6]`. So we want the model to learn to decode each input by adding the previous all inputs. In general it can be a POS tagging or NER tagging or language translation.

**Encoder:** The intension of using encoder is to learn the latent representation of the input vector.

**Decoder:** The decoder is used to decode the targets from the latent representation of the inputs. A vanilla decoder takes in the output of the previous step as its input to predict the current target state. i.e it is conditioned on the previous output `p(y_pred_i|y_pred_i-1)`

**Teacher Forcing:** In teacher forced training instead of using previous output we use the ground truth to predict the current target state i.e `p(y_pred_i|y_truth_i-1)`. Once we train the model, for making predictions we use `p(y_pred_i|y_pred_i-1)`

So the `decoder_input` is the actual target labels shifted to right by one timestep and the first timestep is a special input called start of the sequence.

### Pictorial representation:

#### Training Phase

[image]

#### Prediction/Testing Phase

[image]

### Code sample:

```
X = np.random.randint(1,10,size=(10,sequence_length))
y = X.cumsum(axis=1)

encoder_input_data = X
decoder_input_data = np.column_stack([np.zeros(len(y)), y])[:,:-1]
target_data = y


latent_dim = 32
sequence_length = 5
input_vocabulary_size = 10
hidden_size = 128
output_vocabulary_size = 91

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(sequence_length,))
word_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=input_vocabulary_size,
                           output_dim=hidden_size,
                           trainable=True)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)(word_embedding)



decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(sequence_length,))
word_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=output_vocabulary_size, 
                           output_dim=hidden_size,
                           trainable=True)(decoder_inputs)

decoder_lstm,_,_ = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)(
    word_embedding, initial_state=[state_h, state_c])
outputs = Dense(output_vocabulary_size, activation='softmax')(decoder_lstm)


model = Model([encoder_inputs,decoder_inputs], outputs)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])

model.fit([encoder_input_data,decoder_input_data], to_categorical(y, num_classes=91), epochs=500)
```

As you can see in the code I'am using `0` as the special start symbol (`$` in the figures). The line you should pay attention to is

`decoder_input_data = np.column_stack([np.zeros(len(y)), y])[:,:-1]` it is the target labels shift to right by 1 and special start symbol (0) appended in the beginning.

Comment: I understand, so if I already have decoder_input with this special start symbol, then target labels must be the same decoder_input but shifted to left one timestep and appended a <pad> symbol to the end?? The problem with to_categorical function is that I have a vocabulary of more than 10 000 words, and that gives me a MemoryError. Is there another way to create my target_data?? thanks in advance.

Comment: @10K output vocab is not a big size at all. Since your output vocab is 10K you will need a softmax of 10K. There are some ways like hierarchical softmax but they are meant to speed up the training. Try things like dropping target labels which occur say less in 5% and assign a 'RARE' target to them in the training data. Or reducing the batch size or reducing the number of parameter in your model or even reducing the sequence lenght.

Comment: What happen if I have a huge dataset for traning, can I split my data for example in four pieces and train my model for one piece at a time. Is that correct?? My model will get better results??

Comment: @VictorE23 that is perfectly ok as long as your lables/targers are well represented in all the pieces. I.e make sure the targets are not imbalanced heavily in different splits.